# How does this MATLAB code sample from the Multinomial distribution?

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, distribution

I am reading [this paper about PFA](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.3605.pdf)
and trying to understand the author's code about the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

I do not understand why the authors were using 2 separated matrices to sample from a multinomial distribution instead of a single 3-D matrix `x_pik` as indicated in the paper.

*mult_rand.m*

```
function [x_pk,x_kn] = mult_rand(X,Phi,Theta)
    P = size(X,1); [K,N] = size(Theta);
    x_pk = zeros(P,K); x_kn = zeros(K,N);

    for n=1:N
        inz = find(X(:,n))';
        map = bsxfun(@times,Phi(inz,:),Theta(:,n)'); % P x K
        map = cumsum(map,2);
        x_kp = zeros(K,numel(inz));
        for m=1:numel(inz)
            x_kp(:,m) = x_kp(:,m) + mrand(X(inz(m),n),map(m,:));
        end
        x_kn(:,n) = sum(x_kp,2);
        x_pk(inz,:) = x_pk(inz,:)+x_kp';
    end
end
```

*mrand.m*

```
function x = mrand(n,cp)
    % cp = cumsum( p );
    x = sum(bsxfun(@gt,rand(n,1)*cp(end),cp),2)+1;
    x = sparse(x,1,1,numel(cp),1);
end
```

I am not really sure how *mrand.m* is working to generate the sample. How is this function generating samples from the proper distribution?

[Reference code](https://github.com/zhegan27/dpfa_icml2015/blob/master/support/) available.

Comment: Could someone help me understand the code